# how to solve "EOFError: EOF when reading a line" error in python3?

Tags: python, pycharm, runtime

I'm totally new to python. I want to write a program which checks whether a number is squared or not. my code:

```
import math
T = int(input())

while T >= 0:
    num = int(input())
    sqrt = int(math.sqrt(num))

    if sqrt * sqrt == num:
        print('1')
    else:
        print('0')

    T = T - 1
```

the code is working correctly in my IDE(**pycharm community 2017**) but it gets a runtime error as you see in online IDEs ([on geeksforgeeks ide](https://ide.geeksforgeeks.org/)):

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/043265f1cbdf257ecc20a7579588a4a4.py", line 5, in <module>
    num = int(input())
EOFError: EOF when reading a line
```

Comment: You need to post the code and error here, as text.

Comment: your code works on my computer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change it to:

```
while T > 0:
```

You are requesting 6 numbers if you compare for `>=` and your example only provides 5.

Maybe better:

```
import math

for _ in range(int(input)):
    num = int(input())
    sqrt = int(math.sqrt(num))

    if sqrt * sqrt == num:
        print('1')
    else:
        print('0')
```

and remove the `T`

Answer (score 2):

The value you're setting for `T` is 5, which means the while loop will run 6 times, but you're only providing 5 integers. That's why it tries to read an additional line and gives you the error.

So you should change the condition in your while loop to:

```
while T > 0:
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes, Change it to :

```
    while T>0:
```

you are only providing 5 values. EOF Error happens if no data is given to *input()*. It is also explained in the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/exceptions.html#exceptions.EOFError)

Answer (score 0):

Where do people get the idea or proof that the variable T was ever set to 5 in the first place?

I'm having this same problem randomly in my installation of Pydroid 3. All I can think is that I must have inadvertently installed the wrong libraries in my environment. I removed all of the imports and code other than c=input() followed by print(c) and I am still getting the error when it tries to run the input function, at all, period. It's a bug I keep seeing but occasionally it works!

Comment: checkout the accepted answer that worked for me.